# Excel VlookUp function with conditon ''or''

Tags: excel, vlookup

I Have two excel files:

First file :

```
Store name   ID distributor 1    ID distributor 2     ID distributor 3
 Apple         ID10               ID200               ID5000
 Nokia         ID30               ID400               ID6000
```

Second File is a list of mix ID from different distributors

```
Distributor ID code      Strore Name
1- ID10                      ?
2- ID400                     ?
3- ID5000                    ?
```

Is it possible to make a VLOOKUP function which will try to find a match in **ID distributor 1** and IF no match, look up in **ID distributor 2** and IF no match, look up in **ID distributor 3**. I have about 7 columns of different IDs for the same store name.

For each ID then, it will return the store name in my column 'Store Name' in sheet 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Index/Aggregate:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$D$100)/(Sheet1!$B$1:$D$100=A1),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: so it will return the store name in my second column 'Store Name' of my second file?

Comment: You would replace the references to the correct ones but yes this will find the first row that has a match in the range of columns.

Comment: The 15 means it is looking for the lowest number, and the 7 tells it to ignore errors.