# Multiple results with V.Lookup in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two columns of numeric value, I did the V.Lookup by giving as input an object of column one to have the correspondence of the second column.
The problem is some objects in the first column are repeated and have more than one match on the second column.

**Here's an example:**

This is my sheet:

```
A  B

3  200
7  300
15  500
21  600
21  650
13  800
```

In my V.Lookup, when i search for the element "21" in the column "A", It shows me only "600"
I would like to see every matches

Maybe is it possibile with a Macro? How can I do it?
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: if you have office 365 use FILTER(). If not there are many many examples how to do this on this site using: `INDEX(LARGE())` or `INDEX(AGGREGATE())`

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, has provided this solution quite a lot of times, please search `StackOverflow` here is one for you [Return_Multiple_Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361544/excel-vlookup-function-with-conditon-or)

Comment: Or this one, will give you all the solutions Sir has given with `INDEX()` and `AGGREGATE()` [INDEX()/AGGREGATE()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4851590+INDEX+AGGREGATE)